# Prop from the bottom component to the top component in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to get `fullName` and `ID` in the lower component and pass it to the upper component and use it in the upper component, but I do not know how this is possible, please help

`contacts` and `setcontacts` is my state that is prop

By displaying the `map()`, I display all the contacts and put a button for each of them. I want the `fullName`, `id` and `phone` of the same contact to be sent to the top component when each button is clicked.

```js
//Top component
const MainContent = ({contacts,setcontacts}) => { 
  return (
    <div>
       <p>{contact.fullName}</p>
       <p>{contact.phone}</p> 
       <p>{contact.id}</p> 

      <Contacts contacts={contacts}/>
    </div>
  );
};
export default MainContent;

//Component down
const Contacts = ({contacts}) => {
  const handleBtn = () => {
   //Send the same contact information as clicked to the component above
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {contacts.map((contact) => (
        <div key={contact.id}>
          <p>{contact.fullName}</p>
          <p>{contact.phone}</p>
          <div>
            <button onClick={handleBtn}>send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contacts;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send a callback from child to update the state in parent component.

Check demo here - https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-child-parent-comp-k2fnn

Answer (score 0):

Just try moving `hadleBtn` to `contact` scope within the `map` callback:

```
const Contacts = ({ contacts }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {contacts.map((contact) => {
        const handleBtn = () => {
          console.log(contact.id, contact.fullName);
        };
        return (
          <div key={contact.id}>
            <p>{contact.fullName}</p>
            <p>{contact.phone}</p>
            <div>
              <button onClick={handleBtn}>send</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Now, by doing this, the information of that contact is available in the above component ?!

Comment: I want to click on the button to send the information of that contact to the top component and receive it in the top component and then use

Answer (score 0):

3 solutions here:

1/ Pass function from Top component to Bottom component
2/ useContext -> https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
3/ use redux -> https://redux.js.org/

Comment: Yes, you are right, these are the best methods, but they should not have been used in this case. Thanks again for sharing your opinion. :)